# Random Color Patterns

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns

I'm trying to create hexagonal pattern of slightly offset colors. Similar to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)'s background, but with hexagons.

I've attempted to draw a hexagon and slightly change the colors but doing this ~800 times would be highly impractical.

So essentially, how would I create a group objects with slightly different colors for each

Here's a rough example of what I've tried so far.

[image: Rough Example]

Comment: Please formulate your question more clearly. What is it you want to achieve and have problems with? Thanks!

Comment: A simple google query lead me to this: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/450301?start=0&tstart=0, which really looks like what you are after.

Comment: @Jongware Im not sure that qualifies if he wants every item to have different color and not just swatches but yes randomizing scripts exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quickly written Javascript to randomize the RGB fill color of a selected set of objects:

```
var adjustRanges = {
  red:{min:-40, max:40},
  green:{min:-40, max:40},
  blue:{min:-40, max:40}
};

objects = app.selection;
for (i=0; i<objects.length; i++)
{
  color = objects[i].fillColor;
  if (color instanceof RGBColor)
  {
    r = color.red+adjustRanges.red.min+Math.random()*(adjustRanges.red.max-adjustRanges.red.min);
    if (r < 0) r = 0; if (r > 255) r = 255;

    g = color.green+adjustRanges.green.min+Math.random()*(adjustRanges.green.max-adjustRanges.green.min);
    if (g < 0) g = 0; if (g > 255) g = 255;

    b = color.blue+adjustRanges.blue.min+Math.random()*(adjustRanges.blue.max-adjustRanges.blue.min);
    if (b < 0) b = 0; if (b > 255) b = 255;

    c = new RGBColor();
    c.red = r; c.green = g; c.blue = b;

    objects[i].fillColor = c;
  }
}
```

Save as "changeColors.jsx" in your local Illustrator's Scripts folder so it will appear in the File > Scripts menu next time you restart Illustrator, or anywhere else (and you'll have to browse for its location).

You can change the `min/max` adjustment values at will; for example, setting these values to `0` for both red and blue will only change the Green component.

Comment: +1 you might want to randomize in **HSB** space though And make the channel randomize a function ;) DRY is after all a thing... yeah i know.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to accomplish randomizing these colors.

### Option 1: Randomill

I've made a plugin called [Randomill](https://randomill.com) which can accomplish this. You can dial in a range of colors, and all selected objects will have their fill colors randomized from that range.

[image: Randomill's Random Fill Color Illustrator Script]

### Option 2: Random Swatches Fill Script

Alternatively, there's a free script out there called 'Random Swatches Fill' that can randomize objects' colors from a pre-selected group of swatches. What you could do is create a ton of swatches with varying shades of green and then use this script to randomize the colors of your hexagons.

Answer (score -4):

To get uniform graphics use the snap to grid setting, you can then scale it to your desired size in Illustrator. Check out Chris Spooners blog post about a similar sort of project.

http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-create-a-christmas-jumper-pattern-in-illustrator

Comment: Hello and welcome. I dont think he is asking about how to align the hexagons. As that should be easy. Its the changing of the colors bit thats a problem.